# Pattern unlock not working after OS upgrade to android 6.0.1 Sansung J7

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, locked-out, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-j7

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy J7 device from system update menu. It was working fine after the upgrade but it is not accepting my pattern after the restart. I don't remember the PIN also.

I have tried following things to unlock the device :

1. I have tried logging on to Android Device Manager, but there is nothing like resetting password there in the options. It just allows you to display some message on the device.
2. I have tried unlock through Samsung website but looks like this is something I should have setup before the device was locked up.
3. I have tried pushing Aroma File Manager zip file through `adb sideload` and also through SD Card but through both ways it is giving same error :
   `E:footer is wrong E:Signature verification failed`

To disable Signature verification I tried pushing CWM custom recovery but I am not able to sideload that also as I get the same error.

The recovery is only giving me option to connect to adb sideload. So, I can't delete files through adb shell.

Please tell what other methods I can try.

Comment: Sideloading custom recoveries like CWM or TWRP won't work as they are not cryptographically signed by Samsung and as such the stock (default) recovery will refuse to install it. Also, factory resetting your device no longer resets the lock since Android 5.0 Lollipop, it's an anti-theft measure. Does your device require the pattern on startup (on a black screen) or just on the lock screen? Does it ask for a PIN on startup instead of the pattern? You can try contacting Samsung support or a nearby service center to help, but the phone is most probably encrypted and your data will be deleted.